# Making a Page that uses x-editable into a static page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, x-editable

So I am making a angular-js based page where everything is entirely inline editable using x-editable.

1. Could I make the page static after clicking a button.
2. How could I post using ng-ckeditor

   ```
   <script> 
     var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize','xeditable','ngCkeditor']); 
   </script>
   <h2 id="title" editable-text="title"><a ng-href={{link}} onaftersave="$http.post("$scope.thing")>{{title}}</a></h2>
   <p id ="descr ng-model="descr" ckeditor="editorOptions"></p>
   ```

I want this one page to be capable of saving and be sent to someone else to view and not have the option of editing.

Example:

say my page has one article with the title of "Ex1" with a description of "this is a first draft"

I change the title to "Ex2" and description to "the second draft" using the inline ckeditor.

I want to save the page (a simple ctrl-s) and send it to someone else so they can add another article to the page.

The second person adds an article with title "art2" with descr "this article is..." and changes the first article title to "art1"

Now that the page is done I want to save this html file and send it to someone else for final viewing and they cannot do any inline-editing or anything.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: 1) by 'make the page static', do you mean non-editable?

Comment: yeah. sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: how are you planning on sending the page to someone else?

Comment: If you mean "sending" by I do the edits and send the link to the other user who will see my edits but not be able to edit ? then you need to save (to db) on submit and initialize x editable form based on user.

Comment: Everything would be done locally cause they want the file to be emailed to several people.

Comment: More details needed, not enough information provided to help. - what do you mean the file to be edited to several people??  - please help us help you by providing an MCVE... Please read our Help section on how to create an  MCVE: 
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.